# Salvaging Arduino board from Google ADK 2012

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, usb, arduino-due

I found an old Google ADK 2012 in my closet and remembered it came with a Arduino board (?), an ARM 32-bit Cortex M3 micro-processor available at the time (possibly the DUE).

The ADK 2012 design files and source code were included as part of a software download at the event which is no longer available on the Android site, but I found a mirror here:

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/adk/adk2.html

You can also see the kit in action from the Google I/O 2012 event where these kits were given out:

https://youtu.be/ZUaKSs3utrs

Here's my issue(s):

- When I try to set up and run the ADK 2012 IDE, I get an error stating "ADK2012.app" needs to be updated and disabled overlay on the icon.
- When I try to use the ADK Alternative Build System, I get an error stating `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`, which makes sense because Apple removed the ability to compile 32 bit programs on macOS starting with Xcode 10 (my Xcode: 13.4.1; macOS: 12.6.7)
- After connecting the board to my computer via USB to micro-USB, when I open the Arduino IDE, I'm able to select the port, but there is no option for this particular board, although from everything I've gathered, its essentially a custom version of the Arduino DUE made just for that event, and others have managed to [load the ADK 2012 onto a regular DUE](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-due-and-adk-2012/135978?page=3). So I've been trying it with both Arduino DUE boards (native and programmable)
- When I try to "Get Board Info" in Arduino IDE, the board name is "Unknown board", but all the other information is available (VID, PID, SN).
- After importing the ADK2 library into Arduino IDE and updating the demo code from the source download, I'm able to get the project sketch file to compile and verify without errors, however when I attempt to upload the changes to the board, I receive the following error: `No device found on cu.usbserial-AH015U12 Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1`. The device appears connected to my computer the whole time, including before and after the error.

I think I've exhausted all of my known options and just want to know whether & how it's possible to salvage a 10+ year old (modded but virtual identical) Arduino board.

TLDR; want to tinker with old Arduino board, custom IDE no longer works, Arduino IDE disconnects when attempting upload. Still salvageable or too old?